# JavaScript Switch Statements - possible to use case value?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I was wondering if it is possible to use something similar to 'this' in a Javascript switch statement when executing blocks of code.

For example:

```
switch(x) {
    case 'The pyramids of Giza':
        console.log(this);
        break;
    case 'The Leaning Tower of Pisa':
        console.log(this);
        break;
    default:
        console.log('Not found');
}
```

Is the same as:

```
switch(x) {
    case 'The pyramids of Giza':
        console.log('The pyramids of Giza');
        break;
    case 'The Leaning Tower of Pisa':
        console.log('The Leaning Tower of Pisa');
        break;
    default:
        console.log('Not found');
}
```

This is purely just for efficiency purposes, thanks!

Comment: Just use `x` in the code between the `case` and the `break`. Longer explanation coming up!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, just discovered that I am an idiot because if it's the same value I would just use `x`!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have access to the variable that you're testing within the `switch` statement; after all, if `x` is equal to "The pyramids of Giza", then `x` must also be the value you wish to use within that `case`.

```
switch(x) {
    case 'The pyramids of Giza':
        console.log(x); // output: 'The pyramids of Giza'
        break;
    case 'The Leaning Tower of Pisa':
        console.log(x); // output: 'The Leaning Tower of Pisa'
        break;
    default:
        console.log('Not found');
}
```

Comment: Some things are so easy, that we fail to consider them!

Comment: The only issue (unless I'm missing something) would be if I'm doing `switch(someCPUIntensiveFunction())`. The still-relatively-obvious solution is to cache the result of `someCPUIntensiveFunction()` prior to the switch statement, and switch based on that—but IMO it would be nice to avoid the extra line.

Comment: (In my case, the function I'm switching _probably_ isn't CPU intensive at all—but it would be nice if I could code in a way that avoids extra function calls, just in case.)

Comment: @Wowfunhappy: yeah, it would be advisable to cache - rather than recalculate - a variable reference, particularly in the situation wherein the calculation is expensive.

Answer (score 3):

When you visit a `case:`, the value of the value specified in the `case:` is always the variable put in the `switch` statement. This is because a `case:` is only visited if the variable is equal to the value specified in `case:` in the first place, so you know that if you've visited that case, then the value of the variable must be the same as the value specified in the `case:`. Thus, this is the code you're looking for:

```
switch(x) {
    case 'The pyramids of Giza':
        console.log(x);
        break;
    case 'The Leaning Tower of Pisa':
        console.log(x);
        break;
    default:
         console.log('Not found');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(x) {
    case 'The pyramids of Giza':
        console.log(x);
        break;
    case 'The Leaning Tower of Pisa':
        console.log(x);
        break;
    default:
        console.log('Not Found');
}
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning the value in HTML you can write it like this

```
switch(x) {
    case 'The pyramids of Giza':
        return `<button class="badge text-white">${x}</button>`
        break;

    case 'The Leaning Tower of Pisa':
        return `<button class="badge text-blue">${x}</button>`
        break;
    default:
        console.log('Not Found');
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).